# EasleJS adding shapes to container

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, createjs

my code was working fine up until I tried to add those bezier shapes to a container then my shapes disappeared. Adding them directly to the stage works but adding them to the container then to the stage didn't.

```
    var stage;
    var graphics;
    var crossShape;
    var innerRingsShape;
    var ringShape;
    var centreShape;
    var shapeContainer;
    var queue;
    var logoSize = 300;
    var logoPosX = 600;
    var logoPosY = 150;

    var logoRadius = logoSize / 2;
    var rotateDegrees = [90,180,270,360];



    function init() {
        stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
        queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);

    }

    function buildShapes(){
        var graphicsCross = new createjs.Graphics();
        var graphicsInnerRings = new createjs.Graphics();
        var graphicsCentre = new createjs.Graphics();
        var graphicsRing = new createjs.Graphics();

        shapeContainer = new createjs.Container();
        shapeContainer.x = logoPosX + 100;
        shapeContainer.y = logoPosY + 100;
        shapeContainer.regX = 0;
        shapeContainer.regY = 0;

        graphicsCross.setStrokeStyle(1); graphicsCross.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0)); graphicsCross.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0));
        graphicsInnerRings.setStrokeStyle(1); graphicsInnerRings.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0)); graphicsInnerRings.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,255,255));
        graphicsCentre.setStrokeStyle(1); graphicsCentre.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0)); graphicsCentre.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,255,255));
        graphicsRing.setStrokeStyle(1); graphicsRing.beginStroke(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0)); graphicsRing.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0,0,0));

        graphicsRing.drawCircle(logoRadius,logoRadius, logoRadius - 4);

        graphicsRing.beginFill(createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255,255,255));

        graphicsRing.drawCircle(logoRadius,logoRadius, logoRadius - 14);

        ringShape = new createjs.Shape(graphicsRing);
        ringShape.x = logoPosX;
        ringShape.y = logoPosY;
        ringShape.regX = logoRadius;
        ringShape.regY = logoRadius;

        graphicsCross.moveTo(59,70);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(57,74,56,78,55,81);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(72,92,89,102,107,112);
        graphicsCross.lineTo(107,111);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(106,109,105,107,104,105);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(96,90,88,75,81,60);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(80,59,79,58,77,59);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(74,60,71,60,67,61);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(108,19,185,15,231,61);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(227,60,224,60,220,59);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(219,58,218,58,218,60);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(209,77,200,94,191,110);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(191,111,191,111,191,112);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(209,102,226,92,243,81);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(242,78,241,74,240,70);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(278,111,280,186,240,229);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(241,226,241,223,242,221);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(243,219,242,218,241,217);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(226,209,212,200,198,192);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(196,191,194,190,191,188);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(192,190,193,192,194,194);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(202,209,210,224,217,239);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(218,241,219,241,221,241);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(224,240,227,239,231,238);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(192,279,115,286,67,238);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(71,239,74,240,78,241);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(79,241,80,241,80,240);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(89,223,98,206,107,189);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(107,189,107,189,107,188);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(89,198,72,208,55,218);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(56,222,57,226,59,230);
        graphicsCross.bezierCurveTo(20,190,17,114,59,70);

        crossShape = new createjs.Shape(graphicsCross);
        crossShape.x = logoPosX;
        crossShape.y = logoPosY;
        crossShape.regX = logoRadius;
        crossShape.regY = logoRadius;

        graphicsInnerRings.moveTo(183,206);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(185,211,188,216,190,221);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(168,235,132,236,108,221);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(110,216,113,211,115,206);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(138,218,160,218,183,206);

        graphicsInnerRings.moveTo(183,92);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(160,80,138,80,115,92);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(113,87,110,82,108,77);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(129,63,166,61,190,77);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(188,82,185,87,183,92);

        graphicsInnerRings.moveTo(75,111);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(80,114,85,117,90,120);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(81,139,81,158,90,178);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(85,181,80,184,76,187);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(64,173,64,128,75,111);

        graphicsInnerRings.moveTo(223,111);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(235,132,235,166,223,187);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(218,184,214,181,209,179);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(209,178,209,177,209,176);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(216,159,217,142,210,125);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(210,124,210,123,209,122);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(209,122,209,121,208,120);
        graphicsInnerRings.bezierCurveTo(213,117,218,114,223,111);


        innerRingsShape = new createjs.Shape(graphicsInnerRings);
        innerRingsShape.x = logoPosX;
        innerRingsShape.y = logoPosY;
        innerRingsShape.regX = logoRadius;
        innerRingsShape.regY = logoRadius;

        graphicsCentre.drawCircle(logoRadius,logoRadius,35);

        centreShape = new createjs.Shape(graphicsCentre);
        centreShape.x = logoPosX;
        centreShape.y = logoPosY;
        centreShape.regX = logoRadius;
        centreShape.regY = logoRadius;

        shapeContainer.addChild(ringShape, crossShape, innerRingsShape, centreShape);

        stage.addChild(shapeContainer);
        stage.update();
    }

    function handleComplete(event) {
        var ball = new createjs.Shape();
        buildShapes();

        ball.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
        ball.x = 150;
        ball.y = 400;

        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

        stage.addChild(ball);

    }

    function tick(event) {
        stage.update();
    }
```

Comment: You may be interested in the method chaining that EaselJS supports, so you can do `graphics.lineTo().lineTo().moveTo().curveTo().etc()`. Should clean up your code a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code and got the containers working but not sure quite how/.